# Android icon weird rendering on Huawei P20

Tags: android, android-studio

I've added an icon to my app via the built-in Image Asset Studio in Android Studio.

Made a png foreground and then color as a background.

On a Samsung device, the icon renders perfectly.

[image: App icon on a Samsung Device]

Then when I install the app on a Huawei P20 with android 10. The icon is rendered like this:

[image: App icon Huawei P20]

I think the Huawei UI isn't using the adaptive icon, but uses the legacy icon and adjusts it into its custom app shape UI and therefore zooms in.

Are there some extra steps I need to do for having a good rendering app icon?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Adaptive Icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive)?

Instead of using a single image use the combination of 2 images for `Foreground` and `background`.

You can take the idea from android's default app icon, it's also adaptive.

Comment: Yes I use adaptive icon, but for whatever reason, the huawei p20 uses the legacy icon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Huawei P20 Lite (Android 8.0.0) when I tried to install an app from Android studio.

There's nothing we can do to fix it.
But the icon will look like it should after a reboot.

Also, if you'll build a release version of your app and install it via `adb install` the icon will look like you expect.